# Does a first gen PSP battery cause damage to a PSP 2000

Tags: hardware, psp

I have 2 PSP's, one is a first gen PSP which I use for playing games on the go, the other is a PSP 2000 which I use for when I want to play PSP games on my TV

Recently I found out that the battery for my PSP 2000 is dead, it won't charge however I learned that my first gen PSP betters can still go in and run it but at the cost of not being able to put the battery cover back on

Now looking at the batteries, they both say 3.6v but my first gen PSP says 1800mAh while the PSP 2000 is less, I think 1200

I am wondering what kind of damage I could be doing to my PSP 2000 by using a first gen PSP's battery, I do plan on getting a new battery for my PSP 2000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A higher capacity (mAh) will not ruin your PSP 2000. Extended batteries are ones that have been made with more capacity (mAh), or amps, in order to power its device for a longer period of time. If your PSP (1st gen) has been powered by a lower capacity (mAh) battery, switching to an extended battery with a higher capacity (mAh) will not harm your PSP 2000. Devices can only be damaged when the voltages don't match up.